# React-Native Android Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'root._')

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am having problems running my app, specifically on Android at the moment. When I run react-native run-android and start the app (with or without running react-native start beforehand) I get the following error: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'root._'). I am then unable to launch the debugger because this gives me a timeout whilst connecting to remote debugger error.

[image: Error shown]

[image: Debugger error]

My loading process for the application is as follows:
index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import setup from './src/setup'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('appname', setup)
```

setup.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

import Spinner from './components/common/Spinner'
import App from './App'

import styles from './styles/setup'

export class Root extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      // store: configureStore(this.onStoreLoaded.bind(this))
    }
  }

  onStoreLoaded() {
    this.setState({
      loaded: true,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (

    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Spinner/>
    </View>
  )
  }
}

export default function setup() {
  return Root
}
```

I have commented out the store loading for now because this seems to have become apparent since adding redux but the configure store looks as follows:

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, compose} from 'redux'
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import reducers from '../reducers'

const middlewares = [
  thunk
]

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  undefined,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    autoRehydrate()
  )
)

export default function(callback) {
  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [],
    storage: AsyncStorage
  }, callback)

  return store
}
```

I am using react-native 0.53.0 with the redux version being 3.7.2 and react-redux 5.0.6. I have tried re bundling the code as follows:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I have also tried: adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

I have also updated my build tools and gradle etc in Android studio and everything syncs fine.